# If a race grants "spellcasting as a 1st level sorcerer" would a prestige class that advances spellcasting classes advance these spells?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, dnd-3e, prestige-class, races, dragonlance

The racial ability in question is from the Dragonspawn.
"All spawn gain the ability to cast spells as 1st-level Sorcerers. If the base creature already possessed levels in Sorcerer, then the dragonspawn's effective sorcerer level increases by +1."

And the specific class I'm looking at is the Eldritch Theurge.  Though the question would still apply to any class that advances arcane spellcasting class levels.

Comment: Already got ya covered.

Comment: @KRyan I am not sure that it covers specifically what he is asking. The example for the question you answered, states in the Sandstorm book, specifically, that if the Marrutact takes levels of wizard, it stacks with his racial spellcasting. The Dragonspawn does not mention that.

Comment: @Ruut Dragonspawn does not need to, since that’s the default rule anyway.

Comment: @KRyan could you give me a book and page number detailing that default rule? The Aranea casts spells as a 3rd level sorcerer. Nowhere in the MM or in SS does it say sorcerer levels stack.

Comment: @Ruut This is detailed in my answer to the linked, duplicate question. Specifically, it’s (bizarrely enough) in the section on associated class levels when improving monsters.